# why am i getting 'none' instead a sorted list?

Tags: python, list

```
list = ['apple','Apple','z','Z','banana']
print(list.sort(key = str.lower))
```

It returns none but if i write,

```
list = ['apple','Apple','banana','z','Z']
list.sort(key = str.lower)
print(list)
```

It works fine why?

Comment: Because `list.sort` returns `None`, of course.

Comment: `list.sort` is in-place

Comment: also don't assign anything to `list` function use any variable instead